# XML - Include current month in filepath

Tags: xml

First post, please bear with me. I'm also completely new to XML and don't usually use it, someone else wrote this but have since left the company and I'm just needing to make a small tweak.

At the moment I have a jar file that runs with an XML config file (below) which specifies the path to output the csv file generated by the jar file.

```
<outputDetails>
 <outputFolder>C:\Folder A\Folder B</outputFolder>
</outputFolder>
```

I want the output csv file to be sorted into separate folders by year and then by month (C:\Folder A\Folder B\Year\Month).

How do I go about this? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't do it in XML, but you need to adjust the corresponding Java code which generates the XML.

Comment: I’m not aware that the XML is generated, I thought the config.xml file is just where the settings are configured for use by the Java code. I’m equally unfamiliar with Java so I could be way off.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood that. Still, I think the `config.xml` file is generated somewhere (e.g. maybe by your IDE or something). Sadly I can't help you further than that.

Comment: I would have thought that if the config.xml file is generated somewhere it would overwrite the file each time the .jar file runs. I can change things in the config.xml file and I don't lose those changes when the .jar file is run.

Comment: [Without seeing the jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I cannot really help you... does nobody in your company know where the config.xml file comes from? Have you checked whether maybe some other components of the application generate the config.xml for that .jar file?

Comment: I'll have to ask around again, nobody seemed to know much about it but I'll try again!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not answerable at the XML level.

XML is just a standard for creating markup.  You've posted some application's XML configuration file.  The semantics of that file are defined by the application, not by XML.

If you know empirically that `outputFolder` specifies the output folder to the consuming application, and that when you manually enter your new path that it works too, you have some options:

1. Modify the program that creates the XML config file to use your new, dynamic
   paths.
2. Write code to transform the XML config file to use your new, dynamic
   paths.

How you'd do #2 depends upon which programming languages you know.  XSLT is a great one for XML transformation but many others would work as well.

Comment: Exactly what I tried to explain as well. +1 for the approach #2, I didn't even think of that.